# Gatling .sign issue

Tags: gatling

I am trying to build a Get request as follows and I would like CaseReference value to be populated via feeder `.feed(CaseProviderSeq)`  but for some reason it's not picking CaseReference value and printing following for my println statement in .sign statement bellow

```
PATH KJ: /caseworkers/554355/jurisdictions/EMPLOYMENT/case-types/Manchester_Multiples/cases/$%7BCaseReference%7D/event-triggers/updateBulkAction_v2/token
```

My feeder CSV got following rows currently 
    1574761472170530
    1574622770056940
so I am expecting this amended URL would be like

`/caseworkers/554355/jurisdictions/EMPLOYMENT/case-types/Manchester_Multiples/cases/1574761472170530/event-triggers/updateBulkAction_v2/token`

any idea what wrong I am doing here ??

```
  .get(session =>    SaveEventUrl.replace(":case_reference","${CaseReference}").replaceAll("events", "") + s"event-triggers/${EventId}/token")
  .header("ServiceAuthorization", s2sToken)
  .header("Authorization", userToken)
  .header("Content-Type","application/json")
  .sign(new SignatureCalculator {
 override def sign(request: Request): Unit = {
    val path = request.getUri.getPath
   println("PATH KJ: " + path)
  request.getHeaders.add("uri", path)
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to `.sign`, but your session attribute `CaseReference` not being interpreted. If you look closely you can see the braces [%-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in `$%7BCaseReference%7D`.

Interpretation of the [Gatling Expression Language strings](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/) happens only when a `String` is present when an `Expression[Something]` is needed<sup>1</sup>.

This bug you wrote is shown exactly in the warning in the documentation above.

I believe you can simply remove `session =>` in your `.get`, so you are passing in a `String` rather than a `Session => String`<sup>2</sup>. That string will be implicitly converted to `Expression[String]`. That way Gatling will put the session attribute into the URL.

---

1. This happens because of the Scala implicit conversion.
2. In fact it is `Session => Validation[String]`, because, again, of implicit conversions.